# int x=2; What will *&&&***x return?

Tags: c, pointers

The above expression will breakdown like `*(&(&(&(*(*(*X)))))`

As far as I could solve I think the compiler can trace the value at `(***X)`. But what happens when it tries to retrieve the address of the value i.e'; `&(***X)`. Will this work? Because the value is some random number is an expression. Will the compiler search for the value and return its address? If not what will be the output?

Comment: You can't `&(&x)`.

Answer (score 4):

A compiler error. You can't dereference an int.

Comment: Could you please explain

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is incorrect: `*&&&***x` will not *break down like* `*(&(&(&(*(*(*X)))))`, it will be tokenized as `*` `&&` `&` `*` `*` `*` `x`, resulting in a syntax error.

Adding spaces as in `*& & &***x` will result in a constraint violation because you cannot take the address of an address, nor can you dereference the `int` variable `x` as a pointer.

Conversely, `*&*&*&*&x` is a correct albeit contorted way to take the value of `x`, and so is `0[&x]`.

Comment: what does 0[&x] mean?

Comment: @Sarankumar: `0[&x]` is the same as `*(0 + &x)`, hence the same as `*&x` or `(&x)[0]`. A surprising but correct variation on the array notation.

Comment: @Sarankumar: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below it score.

Answer (score 0):

no, the problem occurs since x is of type int. it contains the value 2. when you say *x, it means "I want the value of the variable that x points to." and you know 2 is not a valid address in memory. this cause error.(the only valid address that you can assign is 0.)
also, since x is of type int, you can't dereference int.you will got a compile error.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is naive but why can't int be de-referenced?

Comment: @Saran kumar You can only dereference a reference, an object which points somewhere. An int points nowhere but an int * a pointer to int can be dereferenced

Comment: @Saran kumar you can only dereference sth that contains address itself. that is a pointer. int type doesn't contain an address.